# How to pre-populate the sms body text without phone on html link in iOS8?

Tags: ios, html, sms

I would like to get support for my question,
I tried

```
href="sms:?body=YYYY"
href="sms:;body=XXXX"
```

both ways doesn't seems to work on iOS8, any help ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems [iOS 8 does it differently](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Oct/09/Prefilling-an-SMS-on-Mobile-Devices-with-the-sms-Uri-Scheme#851137) by using `&` for seperating `sms` and `body` try

```
href="sms:&body=ZZZZ"
```

Comment: @OrenLeibiker I don't have an iOS 8 device with me to test :/ Could you please try with phone number just to see if it works?

Comment: @OrenLeibiker I will test this later but it seems that Apple doesn't officially support this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH7-SW1